# Get set of Checked checkboxes values in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a Generated Checkboxs

```
<?php
                $days = array(
                    'Sat' => 'Saturday',
                    'Sun' => 'Sunday',
                    'Mon' => 'Monday',
                    'Tue' => 'Tuesday',
                    'Wed' => 'Wednesday',
                    'Thu' => 'Thursday',
                    'Fri' => 'Friday'
                );
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($days as $value) {
                        ?>
                        <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="<?= $value; ?>" /> <?= $value; ?><br>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
```

i want to get the selected values With Jquery

i Tried Many ways but it didn't work
...Thank you

Comment: What are the ways you've tried?

Comment: 1 - var checked = $('.days').val();
2 - var checked = $('.days').is(":checked");

i am a very beginner .. sorry for that

Comment: Search on google "jquery get selected checkboxes", 'you'll easily find your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your PHP script, if you would like to have the "key" in the name attribute of the check boxs you would have to write this php script:

```
$days = array(
                'Sat' => 'Saturday',
                'Sun' => 'Sunday',
                'Mon' => 'Monday',
                'Tue' => 'Tuesday',
                'Wed' => 'Wednesday',
                'Thu' => 'Thursday',
                'Fri' => 'Friday'
            );
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    foreach ($days as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'<br>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
```

In your php script the result is: `<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Sunday" /> Sunday<br>`

I don't know why would you like to use JQuery to check which checkBoxs are checked, this can be done easily using the following JavaScript:

The function getCheckedValues() returns an array with all the checked checkBoxs value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Sat" value="Saturday">Saturday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Sun" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Mon" value="Monday">Monday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Tue" value="Tuesday">Tuesday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Wed" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Thu" value="Thursday">Thursday<br>
    <input class="days" type="checkbox" name="Fri" value="Friday">Friday<br>
    <script>
        var daysCheckBoxs = document.getElementsByClassName("days");

        function getCheckedValues()
        {
            var checked = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < daysCheckBoxs.length; i++)
            {
                if (daysCheckBoxs[i].checked)
                {
                    checked.push(daysCheckBoxs[i].value); // If you would like to get the name you can do the following instand daysCheckBoxs[i].name
                }
            }
            return checked;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Vigdorovich

Thank you very much 
I've tried it , and it works

but i had a problem
that when i pass it to a php file , Only the last choice is passed . 
so i tried this and also it works with me

```
var selected ='';
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
            selected += $(this).val()+'-';
        });
```